# How to check whether a method is static in PHP?

Tags: php, methods, static

I need to know whether the method is declared as static given its name and the name of the class containing it. `method_exists` provides `true` for both static and non-static methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [ReflectionMethod::isStatic](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isstatic.php)

Comment: How does this work? The link points to ReflectionClass::getStaticPropertyValue but that's for properties not methods. It should link here: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.isstatic.php but it has no examples, and I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: Figured it out. Adding a new answer.

Comment: $method = new ReflectionMethod ('NameOfClass', 'nameOfMethod');
                                       
$isStatic = $method->isStatic();

Answer (score 15):

Here's a little more clear way on how to use ReflectionMethod:

```
$MethodChecker = new ReflectionMethod($ClassName,$MethodName);
var_dump($MethodChecker->isStatic());
```