# PHP: check if class implements static method

Tags: php

I need to check if a class implements specific method and then call it.
If a method exists and is static it should be called static, otherwise it should be invoked on a class instance (object).
The problem occurs when determining if a method is defined within a class as a static method.

Here is an example code that tests specific instance or class for method existence.

```
class A {
    public function b() {}

    public static function c() {}
}

$instance = new A();

var_dump(method_exists('A', 'b'));
var_dump(method_exists($instance, 'b'));

var_dump(method_exists('A', 'c'));
var_dump(method_exists($instance, 'c'));

var_dump(is_callable(['A', 'b']));
var_dump(is_callable([$instance, 'b']));

var_dump(is_callable(['A', 'c']));
var_dump(is_callable([$instance, 'c']));
```

When executed the output is as following:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

The question is why the result is always true even if the callable argument is passed for static or non static call?

How to test if a method is defined as static without using Reflection?

Comment: You could maybe use Reflection for this

Comment: I could use Reflection, but I'm trying to figure out why is_callable and method_exists are not working as stated in PHP documentation. Also, using Reflection could provoke performance issues.

Comment: @Tez PHP didn't have static methods from the first day. You can even [call non-static methods from a static context (and vice versa)](http://codepad.org/wlLLeMK6), so of course these methods return true, because technically it is possible

Comment: What is wrong with using a reflection method?

Comment: @kingkero Yes, but it's not compliant to PHP strict standards, so I guess that approach won't work in this case.

Comment: @Vanitas there is nothing wrong in using Reflection, though what about performance? Should I avoid it for hundred method calls per request?

Comment: @Tez Sounds like a design decision, do you really need to check if a method exists for hundreds of time?

Comment: agreed, I'm testing Reflection usage and results will be cached somehow. It still bothers me... the inconsistency in posted results versus PHP documentation :)
Perhaps someone can elaborate a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a method is static in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513589/how-to-check-whether-a-method-is-static-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A static function of a class is by definition a *method* of that class and it's also *callable*, hence calling `method_exists` or `is_callable` on a static method will always ***return true***

For your use case you do not need to actually know if the method is static or not, calling

`call_user_func([$instance, 'c']);`

Will do what you want, if `'c'` is a **static method** and `$instance` either an **object** or a **class name**, it will be called 'statically'

Similarly, if you're calling

`call_user_func([$instance, 'b']);`

If `'b'` is a **non static method** and `$instance` an **object**, the method will be called on the object 'non statically'

If you really need to know if the method is static or not, then you should use **Reflection** which is doing excellent in term of performances, against your beliefs

```
$rm = new \ReflectionMethod($instance_or_class, 'b');
$rm->isStatic();
```

Comment: thanks! used ReflectionMethod to check `isStatic()` for `runkit_method_add()` to stub methods in an old/poorly designed code base in desperate need of coverage; runs great and helped keep things simple (don't have to specify whether the method is static or not for every test).